# Facebook message read on desktop, but still marked as unread on Android phone

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

So the problem is, when I'm on my computer and I'm chatting on Facebook through safari, the messages show up as notifications on my phone. They do not go away, even though I am reading them and answering them through my computer. Do any of you know if there is a way to sort of 'sync' this up? Right now, if I chat with 5 people simultaneously on my computer, I have to get rid of five notifications and chat heads on my phone afterwards which is pretty annoying..

Kind regards, Jonas

Comment: Delete Facebook messenger on your phone and use the latest Chrome for Android update with Webkit Push Notifications to browse Facebook. (More secure, still get notifications, no app permissions, FB can't access your SMS/calls but they'll still track you around via cookies for personal advertising...)